# Cannot Connect to MongDB Atlas using Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mern

I am starting to learn a MERN stack tutorial. I initially created a react app, added a directory called backend, installed express, cors, express, and dotenv, then created a server.js and added some code, but after connecting to mongodb atlas, I get the error below:

> (node:5828) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoTimeoutError:
>   Server selection timed out after 30000 ms
>       at Timeout. (C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\REACTion\mernapp\backend\node_modules\mongodb\lib\core\sdam\topology.js:878:9)
>       at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:531:17)
>       at processTimers (internal/timers.js:475:7) (node:5828) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This
>   error originated either by throwing inside of an async function
>   without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled
>   with .catch(). (rejection id: 1) (node:5828) [DEP0018]
>   DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In
>   the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the
>   Node.js process with a non-zero exit code. [nodemon] restarting due to
>   changes... [nodemon] starting `node server.js` Server is running on
>   port: 5000 Connection failed! MongoTimeoutError: Server selection
>   timed out after 30000 ms
>       at Timeout. (C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\REACTion\mernapp\backend\node_modules\mongodb\lib\core\sdam\topology.js:878:9)
>       at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:531:17)
>       at processTimers (internal/timers.js:475:7) {   name: 'MongoTimeoutError',   reason: MongoNetworkError: connection 2 to
>   cluster0-shard-00-01-l6mnq.gcp.mongodb.net:27017 closed
>         at TLSSocket. (C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\REACTion\mernapp\backend\node_modules\mongodb\lib\core\connection\connection.js:356:9)
>         at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:288:20)
>         at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:200:13)
>         at net.js:586:12
>         at TCP.done (_tls_wrap.js:479:7) {
>       name: 'MongoNetworkError',
>       errorLabels: [ 'TransientTransactionError' ],
>       [Symbol(mongoErrorContextSymbol)]: {}   },   [Symbol(mongoErrorContextSymbol)]: {} }

Below is my code for the server.js file. I copied the uri from MongoDB atlas and pasted it in a .env file.

```js
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

require('dotenv').config();

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());

const uri = process.env.ATLAS_URI;
mongoose
  .connect(uri, { useUnifiedTopology: true, useNewUrlParser: true, useCreateIndex: true })
  .then(() => {
    console.log('Connected to database!');
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log('Connection failed!');
    console.log(error);
  });

const connection = mongoose.connection;
connection.once('open', () => {
  console.log('MongoDB database connection established successfully');
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port: ${port}`);
});
```

Comment: For some reason, everything is now working out fine. I guess it was a problem with the mongodb server.

Comment: Yes, you are partly right. Newer driver in node.js with process.env.var not parsing properly. Same string if you are assigning in direct var than it works. Same for connection string and database name too.

Comment: I'm not sure but I think whitelisting all the ip's in atlas might just solve the problem.

Comment: Yes, that's mandatory step. I thought you known about it. If you want to test than you could whitelist all IP Address too. But , that is not recommended way.

Answer (score 2):

I have faced a similar problem like this,
please remove useUnifiedTopology: true or make it false this fixes your problem. I don't know why but this fixed my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you well installed mongoDB in local ?

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/administration/install-community/

Answer (score 0):

Verify the contents of the system environment variables, from a new console window type the command "echo %ATLAS_URI%", if the URI does not appear it is necessary to add it:

1. In Search, search for and then select: System (Control Panel).
2. Click the **Advanced system settings** link.
3. Click **Environment Variables**. In the section **System Variables**, find the PATH environment variable and select it. Click **Edit** If the PATH environment variable does not exist, click New.
4. In the **Edit System Variable** (or **New System Variable**) window, specify the value of the PATH environment variable. Click **OK** Close all remaining windows by clicking **OK**.

If you already have it added it is necessary to restart the computer and try the **"echo %ATLAS_URI%"** command.