# MongoTimeoutError: Server selection timed out after 30000 ms

Tags: mongodb, discord.js

I am taking "Uncaught Promise Error:  { MongoTimeoutError: Server selection timed out after 30000 ms" error in console. What can i do?

Comment: *"What can i do?"* - I would suggest starting by showing a small sample of code that reproduces the problem and a bit more detail about the environment you are connecting to. This is not a chat room. Questions have the general expectation of containing enough information necessary to diagnose and solve **within them** and without protracted discussion prompting you to provide said information. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Looks like mongodb server temporarily went down. Same issue like here  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58568275/cannot-connect-to-mongdb-atlas-using-mongoose

Comment: It's improved on his own, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your MongoDB server is down or inaccessible. **If you're using MongoDB Atlas, you might have forgotten to [whitelist your IP](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/security-whitelist/#add-whitelist-entries).** Here's how to fix it (from the page I just linked):

1. Go to IP Whitelist view.

   - In the Security section of the left navigation, click Network Access. The IP Whitelist tab displays.
   - Click plus icon Add IP Address.
2. Enter an IP address, CIDR block, or Security Group ID.

   > If you're running the bot locally, you can google "what's my IP" and it should show your public IP right on the search page.
3. Click Save and Close.